# What exactly is type `(val: string)` in Swift when calling `type(of: xxx)`

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I am running the follow function on a particular custom type:

```swift
    let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: self)
    print("self \(self)");

    for (propName, propValue) in mirror.children {
        print("propname \(propName) ... \(propValue)", type(of: propValue))
    }
```

And it is printing out

```
self UserAuthInput.userEmail(val: bob@gmail.com)
propname Optional("userEmail") ... (val: "bob@gmail.com") (val: String)
```

I am having a hard time wrapping my head around as a Swift newb what exactly `(val: string)` type means. I know it came from a definition like this:

```swift
    public enum UserAuthInput {

        case userEmail(val: String)

        case userPhone(val: String)
    }
```

However my question is,

1) How can I parse the `bob@gmail.com` out of the `(val: string)` type object `propValue`?

2) How can I check that this particular `self` is of `enum` type thus special handling is needed?

Thank you!

Comment: Is `self` in the first code snippet the `UserAuthInput` enum?

Comment: @Sweeper Yes. I added a print of `self` to clarify further.

Comment: The simplest solution is to remove `val:` from your `case`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a *one-element tuple*. This is confirmed by using another mirror to reflect the child's value:

```
let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: UserAuthInput.userEmail(val: "xxx@example.com"))
for (propName, propValue) in mirror.children {
    print("propname \(propName!) ... \(propValue)", type(of: propValue))
    let subMirror = Mirror(reflecting: propValue)
    print(subMirror.displayStyle!) // tuple

    // this is one way you can get its value
    print(subMirror.children.first!.value) // xxx@example.com
}
```

Normally you can't create one-element tuples, so I'm quite surprised by this too. Since you can't use the type `(val: String)` *in code*, you can't get the associated value's value by simply casting. One way, which I've shown above, is to use another mirror.

This is consistent with the case of 2 or more associated values, which also makes `propValue` be of a tuple type.

```
public enum UserAuthInput {

    case userEmail(val: String, val2: String)

    case userPhone(val: String)
}

let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: UserAuthInput.userEmail(val: "xxx@example.com", val2: "hello"))
for (_, propValue) in mirror.children {
    print(type(of: propValue) == (val: String, val2: String).self) // true
}
```

To check whether the mirror is reflecting an enum, check `displayStyle`:

```
if mirror.displayStyle == .enum {
    // enum!
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You do not describe your types (Mirror), so there is some guessing.

If the problem is how to extract the String:

```
for (propName, propValue) in mirror.children {
    if case .userEmail(let mail) = XXXX { // The value to match. Is it mirror here ?
        print(mail)
    }
    print("propname \(propName) ... \(propValue)", type(of: propValue))
    }
```